# Pulling data from SAP using Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, longtext

So I am trying to pull data from SAP GUI using Excel macros. I am new to VBA so please bear with me. I found a topic on here called VBA pulling data from [SAP GUI for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies) and I am confused.

What I am trying to do is as follows:

1. Copy a notification number from a list in excel.
2. Go to the appropriate screen in SAP and paste this number in the search box.
3. Open the long text box.
4. Copy the long text.
5. Paste into excel.

I can't seem to get by `Set session = connection.Children(0)` to get the first session (window) on that connection.

Any help is much appreciated. The reason I am doing this is because SAP GUI won't export long text and it takes an act of God to get it fixed.

Comment: Do you have server side scripting enabled? Have you tried recording a macro using the built in macro recorder?

Comment: No I haven't, can you do it with SAP's built in macro recorder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA pulling data from SAP for dummies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies)

Comment: You need to make sure server side scripting is enabled then before you can do this. SAP GUI scripts will fail on that call when you do not have scripting enabled.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, I am asking a question about the code, I refrenced it above.

Comment: And server side scripting is enabled.

Comment: Do you have SAP open when you run the macro?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for all my connections for SAP:

```
'Connect to SAP to run automation.
        If Not IsObject(SAP_applic) Then
            Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
            Set SAP_applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        End If
            Set connection = SAP_applic.Children(0)
        If Not IsObject(connection) Then
            Set connection = application.Children(0)
        End If
        If Not IsObject(session) Then
            Set session = connection.Children(0)
        End If
        If IsObject(WScript) Then
            WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
            WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
        End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're wanting to extract the long text information from a notification.  If that is the case, I have a text file that you can import into the visual basic editor and then run that macro in your spreadsheet.  The only thing you need to have is the first column containing the list of your notification number in your spreadsheet (be sure the first notification number starts in cell A2). In cell A1, input Notification number or something like that.  For cell B2 input Description therefore you'll know what each column represents.  I don't know if you're using transaction IQS3 to access your notification, but this is where I go to view all of our notifications that are created.  If not, then hopefully this template my still be of some use to you as a go by or something.

Simply copy and paste the following code below into notepad and save it somewhere that you can access when importing into your spreadsheet.

```
Dim i As Integer
Sub Main()

    Call MsgBox("Excel will minimize during this task to allow you to do some other work while it runs. " _
                & vbCrLf & "" _
                & vbCrLf & "It takes approximately 9 seconds per EWR number to retrieve the data from SAP." _
                & vbCrLf & "" _
                & vbCrLf & "Thanks for your patience and understanding, while the code runs. :)" _
                , vbInformation, "See you soon!")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Cursor = xlWait
        .Visible = False
    End With
    On Error GoTo Main_Error

    If Not IsObject(sapApplication) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set sapApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = sapApplication.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Session) Then
        Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
        WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
        WScript.ConnectObject sapApplication, "on"
    End If
    i = 2
    'For i = 2 To LastRow(Sheet1)
    Do Until Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo errReturn
        Application.StatusBar = "Row: " & i & ": Retrieving details for EWR: " & Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(i, 2) = Populate(Session, Cells(i, 1).Value, i)
        Cells(i, 1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Cells(i, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Cells(i, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        If Not Cells(i, 2).MergeCells = True Then Rows.AutoFit
        i = i + 1
        DoEvents
        'Next i
    Loop

    Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    On Error GoTo 0
errReturn:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Cursor = xlNormal
        .StatusBar = False
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Exit Sub

Main_Error:
    MsgBox "You need to connect to the SAP GUI to use this spreadsheet", vbCritical, "Error"
    GoTo errReturn
End Sub

Function Populate(Session, EWRNumber As String, j As Integer) As String
    On Error GoTo continue
    Dim strpopulate As String
    'Dim j As Integer
    strpopulate = ""
    'j = 1
    With Session
        '.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
        .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nIQS3"
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRIWO00-QMNUM").Text = EWRNumber
        .findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
        .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAB_GROUP_10/tabp10\TAB01/ssubSUB_GROUP_10:SAPLIQS0:7235/subCUSTOM_SCREEN:SAPLIQS0:7212/subSUBSCREEN_1:SAPLIQS0:7715/btnQMICON-LTMELD").press
        .findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[2]/menu[2]").Select
        n = 1
        Do Until .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSTXXEDITAREA/txtRSTXT-TXLINE[2," & n & "]").Text = "________________________________________________________________________"
            strpopulate = strpopulate & .findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLSTXXEDITAREA/txtRSTXT-TXLINE[2," & n & "]").Text
            strpopulate = strpopulate & vbCrLf
            n = n + 1
            'MsgBox (CDbl(n / 29) = CInt(n / 29))
            If CDbl(n / 29) = CInt(n / 29) Then
                Call MergeCells(j)    '= 29
                i = i + 1
                'j = j + 1
            End If
        Loop
        .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
        .findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
    End With
    'MsgBox strpopulate
continue:
    Debug.Print strpopulate
    Populate = strpopulate
End Function

Sub MergeCells(j As Integer)
    Cells(j, 1).Select
    'Insert row below active cell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

    'Merge Selected Cells and Newly inserted Cells
    Cells(j, 1).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
    Cells(j, 2).Select
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge

    ActiveCell.Select
    Cells(j, 1).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(j, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(j, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Cells(j, 2).WrapText = True
    Rows(j).RowHeight = 409
    Rows(j + 1).RowHeight = 409
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and format it in the right way :) tnx