# set up automatic download report from sap to excel

Tags: download, excel-2007, sap-gui

I have to download a report twice day from SAP to Excel. Anybody knows a way to set up automatic download from SAP to excel 2007.

Thanks for your help?

Comment: I would say it depends on the rights you have. If you have just regular user's access then it is a problem, but I am also only a user. It would be probably possible only using AutoIt script or something like that. Also what report, a standard transaction?

Comment: Also there is SAP GUI Scripting http://www.synactive.de/docu_e/specials/guiscripting.html, but in my client it is not visible.

Comment: And a very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies

Comment: Hi VDohnal, I need to download Open delivery report

Comment: It is important to find out, whether you can use SAP scripting or not. http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-57020  If the option is disabled in menu and it is not disabled in Options http://community.worksoft.com/Knowledge-Base/Worksoft-Products/Worksoft-Certify-Interface/Certify-SAP-Interface/configuring-the-sap-gui-to-support-script-recording-and-playback.html, then it is not installed and you cannot use it.

Comment: Does your requirement could be to send the excel file to email?