# How can I impoprt data from SAP system to excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help me out regarding A  standard  code  for importing data from SAP SYSTEM TO EXCEL using VBA.  I use SE16 transaction and a table named .I need to import  data from TFACS table to excel using vba.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA pulling data from SAP for dummies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies)

Comment: Actually my company have disabled the record option in the sap system.I want solution without dummies.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I need to automate the process,its a manual process,with a click in excel the data need to be refreshed in the excel from SAP system using vba.I need the code for it  @eirikdaude

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SE16n you can export directly from there to csv or text file.  You can also get with IT to create a nightly spool that will dump a text file into a folder and then link directly to that file with excel.

Comment: Hello ,Thanks for your reply,I need to automate the process,its  a manual process,with a click in excel the data need to be refreshed in the excel from SAP system using vba.I need the code for it

Comment: Are you currently able to connect directly to a server?  You can create a text file and save as foo.udl then close the file and open it to get your server connection info.  Then write something like the below:

Public Function ObjectConnect(AID As String, APswd As String)

    ObjectConnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.9;Password=" & APswd & ";Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & AID & ";Data Source=ServerName"

End Function

Comment: Otherwise if you cannot connect directly to the server then you need to get IT to create a nightly extract for you.  As I mentioned you can use this extract to automate in excel.  Do something like:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
end sub