# Connect SAP on Citrix through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have no direct SAP installed on my machine and using SAP window through below link.

https://nedc-ctx.applications.services.axa-tech.intraxa/Citrix/AccessPlatform/auth/loggedout.aspx

I am aware of Record and Run function of SAP GUI and that is working. I have this access in training version only. In production I am unable to use run and record option.

How do I open SAP window from Excel VBA, connect and load the data?

In code below I get an error.

I found I am unable to add reference file "sapfewse.ocx" on my machine.

Is it possible to connect SAP through Excel VBA if we access SAP through above provided link. After clicking on above link new pop-up window will get connected with SAP with window. SAP is getting connected through Citrix.

Code (taken from this [help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118767/excel-vba-pulling-data-from-sap-netweaver)):

```
Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI") 'Get the SAP GUI Scripting object
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine 'Get the currently running SAP GUI 
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0) 'Get the first system that is currently connected
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0) 'Get the first session (window) on that connection

'Start the transaction to view a table
session.StartTransaction "SE16"
```

Comment: You use SAP Gui via a Citrix server, right. That means you do not have any of the SAP Gui files installed on your system in order to do SAP scripting. There might be a way to do this via the Citrix server but I have never seen that. And Script Recording is not running on your PC, it is running on the citrix server.

Comment: On solution could be to run SAP and Excel on the same citrix "sandbox" but then you need to involve your IT resp. the administrator of the citrix system.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided would only work if you have the SAP GUI installed on your computer. 
I would suggest asking the IT team if they can provide you the server address so you can use a Remote Function Call to retrieve the data automatically. This can be done with VBA (https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/129358)
You would need to adapt the code in the link to match your needs