# Import data from transaction CKIS

Tags: sap-erp, sap-gui

Does anybody have any knowledge of how to extract data from SAP system through VBA?

I would like to extract data from eg. CKIS (product costing).

It would be helpful with any kind of code, that would connect me to SAP system.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at SAP Gui Scripting. Check the link [VBA pulling data from SAP for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies) for some useful information.

SAP Gui Scripting can be used with VBA to pull data from the SAP System