# When using SAP GUI Scripting in VBA, how can I view SAP GUI objects properties while coding - like in IntelliSense?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Is there a way to view the properties on SAP GUI objects?

Like this:

[image: Properties drop-down for Workbook object]

But for SAP objects like the following ones:

```
Set SAPGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set App = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = App.Children(0)
Set SAPSession = Connection.Children(0)
```

I ask this after reading the last part of the answer to this post: [VBA general way for pulling data out of SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies)

> If however you want to use early binding so that your VBA editor might
> show the properties and methods of the objects you are using, you need
> to add a reference to `sapfewse.ocx` in the SAP GUI installation folder.

Comment: If you've declared your variables as explicit types after adding a reference to the SAP object model then you should be seeing what you want.  Did you do that?

Comment: You mean to add `Option Explicit` as the first line of the code? If yes, I had already done that and it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something so badly advertise by the SAP team, they should definitely do a better job there.

Basically you first of all need to add a reference to the SAP object model, the libraries that VBA will understand. Don't know how familiar are you with there references to object models. Basically, on your VBA Editor, click Tools, then References, then Browse, and find this file: "C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx" (or possibly "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapfewse.ocx").

Now you'll be able to browse it on the Object Explorer (press F2 in the VBE), and declare the types.

You need now to familiarise yourself with the Types of this library. Some hints, they all start with Gui, like, `GuiSession`, `GuiApplication`, `GuiConnection`, GuiBlabla... Names are pretty explicit and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what @Nelson_Vides has said. As he said, you will need to reference the **sapfewse.ocx** file, and you can view the class objects by pressing F2.

However, the IntelliSense will only be visible once you define an object from the SAP class library.

```
Dim userArea As GuiUserArea ' <-- For example
```

Now, whenever the object is used the IntelliSense will show up.

[image]

Best of luck and happy scripting!

Answer (score -1):

SAP also provides documentation on their GUI objects:

[image]