# How do I perform automated reporting in a new SAP session?

Tags: python, reporting, sap-gui

Dears,

Given the following snippet of the record in SAP (which is actually two recordings one after the other):

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 145, 41, false
session.createSession()
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = f"{SAP_transaction}"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VKORG-LOW").text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VKBUR-LOW").text = ""
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUDAT-LOW").text = "16.11.2020"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUDAT-LOW").setFocus()
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_AUDAT-LOW").caretPosition = 10
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_S_VBELN_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press()
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").press()
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
```

In the second line, I'm creating a new session, but then the rest is performed in the old session instead of the new one. How can I perform the task in the new session instead?
I'll be using Python to download and merge some reports, but given the limitations of SAP in providing large sets of data, I have to download stuff multiple times. So, I was willing to implement maybe parallel processing if I could use new SAP sessions.

Thank you in advance for the help.

P.S: in the snippet, I just copy pasted two different recordings in one... and of course it didn't work :)

Comment: SAP GUI can't run script in several sessions in parallel. Only one script at a time, whatever the number of sessions is.

Comment: I do not see eye to eye on that. You can run a "script" in several sessions in parallel. I just tested that "roughly." BUT, I did that with two instances of a programm I wrote to download data from SAP. First instance connected to `ses[0]`, second instance connected to `ses[1]`. Transaction and download ran in parallel. So based on that short test you could try to start two sessions and then you would need two different threads to connect to the different sessions and run your scripts. But that is just an idea.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133033/6600940) is a function to create a new session and connect to it.