# SAP: Copy SAP message to Excel Column

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am not sure what I missed here, I am really new to VB and I would appreciate your time to help me on this. I want to copy message that showing at the corner of SAP to specific column at the same line that it run, and I got error 91 which little confuse. If I remove that line, everything working fine.

Here is part of the code I use

```
Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
..
.
.
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1)End(xlUp).Row
.
For i = 2 To LastRow
objSheet.Cells(i,5).Value = Session.FindByID("wnd[0]/sbar/").Text 'I want the message showing in Cloumn E and them same row it running
```

[image]

Comment: RTE is pretty clear. You did not assign as SAP session to your variable `Session`. So this varaible points to `Nothing`. You have to assign that to a running SAP session. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624238/find-sap-gui-session-opened-for-given-sap-system) might help.

Comment: You also miss a dot '.' before "Value" in this chunk: `objSheet.Cells(i,5)Value`. Should be `objSheet.Cells(i,5).Value`

Comment: @AndreyAmpilogov yes, I add .value but it will not running maybe like Storax said I need to define an open session