# How can i use some SAP scripting from windev?

Tags: vba, windev, sap-gui

I have a windev programm that needs to access some SAP data.
Because of my company's restrictions, i cannot use the SAP native access provided with WinDev.
So, How can I use vba code that uses SAP from windev?

This is for a .exe programm for Windows. I need to go through the SAP GUI, so SAP GUI scripting is used.

Unfortunately, due to my company's restrictions, i do not have any code to show.

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or is this a "How do I do SAP Scripting in VBA?" blanket question. If it's a blanket question, there are plenty of tutorials and already answered questions about how to do this all over the internet, so adding yet another one here is probably not super helpful. If it is a more specific question, please update your question with those specifics.

Comment: [Here's a good generic write up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452461/vba-pulling-data-from-sap-for-dummies) as an example.

Comment: @JNevill no, it is not a blanket question. Windev is an automatic programming software, that does not allow you tu use sap scripting or vba. Thanks for the link though, but i do know how to create a script. :) I specified in my question that i used windev, sorry if that is not clear for you, but windev uses a language (called WLanguage) that does not allow sap scripting to be written "raw" into the code, and i was asking methods without using native access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer !

To use SAP Scripting without using the native access, you can use a Batch file to run your SAP Scripting file.

That is one way of doing it. You can also use an excel file, with macros, and analyze your data there before using those in Windev.

Sure it is a complicated way to do things, but if your company does not allow you to directly read SAP database's tables, you can do it using this method.